# aws mobile hub ionic 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic2, aws-sdk

i want to develop ionic app using aws mobile hub
     i saw https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-aws but not all functionlity are implmented like Facebook login ,push notification ,storage (when i want to make some request to filter data ...)

Morever documentation in amazon are only for ios and android

```
    can any one give me some ressouce where i can acheive what i want ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this sample https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-ionic-sample that has a separate signer that you can leverage.

You can do something like this https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/ to get the token and federate with Cognito Identity as shown here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html

Francisco